# How to write a Debian/rule to copy the file to its target?

Tags: deb

I'm able to create a deb package. Now, I want to write a Debian rule to copy the file to its target.

For example, a script should be copied to `/etc/init.d` be executed after installation.

Note: I followed this blog to build debian package                                                                                           [`https://abz89.wordpress.com/2008/03/24/building-debian-deb-package-from-tarball-source-targz/`](https://abz89.wordpress.com/2008/03/24/building-debian-deb-package-from-tarball-source-targz/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`debian/install`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/dh_install.1.html) instead. A `debian/install` containing:

```
foo /etc/init.d
```

Will cause `foo` to be copied to `/etc/init.d` relative to the package build directory.

Comment: Can you please brief about the debian/install. What i did is I have created file debian/mypackage.install it contains  rule usr/bin
rule etc/init.d/.  Here rule is a file, After building the deb package the rule file is not copied to etc/init.d/ & usr/bin/    Any suggestions

Comment: @Jacob  the path is supposed to be relative to root, so, without a leading slash.

Comment: @prem where would `rule` be located after building the source?

Comment: ...ah, I see. I always use with, never tried without.

Comment: @ muru rule file should be at /etc/init.d/ after building the source

Comment: @prem what? You build the source code and it places the files in your `/etc/init.d`? What insane program are you building?

Comment: @muru actually it's doesn't meant like that. My scenario is I have a shell script file apart from source files. After building, the  script file alone should be place at /etc/init.d .

Comment: @prem So where is that file located?

Comment: @muru for now I'm trying it to kept inside the source file and build it. Please suggest where it should be. I'm very new to making deb

Comment: So if your source code is in `some/where`, and your `debian` directory is `some/where/debian`, `rule` is in `some/where/rule`?

Comment: 1. Source code path ubuntu@ip-10-232-76-3:/opt/uat/elasticsearch-1.4.4$  2. ubuntu@ip-10-232-76-3:/opt/uat/elasticsearch-1.4.4/debian$      3. rule file path ubuntu@ip-10-232-76-3:/opt/uat/elasticsearch-1.4.4/debian$

Comment: @prem if `rule` is in `debian/`, then `install` should have `debian/rule etc/init.d`

Comment: @muru where is the install path?

Comment: `debian/install` or `debian/<package>.install`

Comment: @muru FYI I dont see any file like that. ubuntu@ip-10-232-76-3:/opt/uat/elasticsearch-1.4.4/debian$ ls -ltr ins*
ls: cannot access ins*: No such file directory                                                       Even debian/<package>.install is also not there. Please suggest

Comment: You create it, if course. And stop including the prompt. It just makes things hard to read.

Comment: I have created as you per your suggestion. EG mypackagename.install it has debian/rule etc/init.d. After that I build the package and installed like dpkg -i package name . But still the rules file is not going to etc/init.d

Comment: Where is `mypackagename.install` located, now? And what are you using in `debian/rules`?

Comment: It's in debian/<packagename>.install

Comment: @ muru please suggest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29241/discussion-between-prem-and-muru).